# How to use Jcrop() for jquery on DOM generated at the future?

Tags: jquery

I'm using `jcrop` for jquery to crop images. To use it, I'm using `$(function(){ $('#jcrop').Jcrop(); });`.

My problem is that, the target element `#jcrop` is generated using ajax. So when I use the above code, it doesn't recognized the DOM element.

How do I change the code to make it work with `.live()`??

Comment: have you checked out the dojo.Deferred interface?

Comment: Sorry. I've no idea what Dojo is??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is an alternative to the .`live()` method and is the recommended way to go. Delegate your event to run when dynamic #jcrop element is loaded:

```
$("body").delegate("#jcrop", "load", function(){
    $(this).Jcrop();
});
```

Comment: I'm a little confused here. The `load` event is of the DOM `#jcrop` and not of the selector `body` here???

Comment: The load event applies to the dynamic '#jcrop' element. We use 'body' only because we know that it may eventually contain '#jcrop'.  So really, you could replace 'body' with any other element that will contain '#jcrop'. It is nothing more than a container element that will never change and that we can safely delegate your event to.